# How do I retrieve the currency details of a journal transaction from the REST API in Acumatica?

Tags: api, rest, acumatica, currency

I’m having a hard time making sense of multi-currency transactions. I’m using the REST API to retrieve journal transaction details. I’m hitting the /entity/Default/18.200.001/JournalTransaction endpoint with $expand=Details and some date filters. The base currency of this Acumatica instance is USD, but some journal transactions are entered in EUR. The problem is that for these EUR transactions, I have no way of knowing these debit/credit amounts were entered in the non-default currency. I see the EUR amount, but the CurrencyID of the transactions indicates “USD”. About the only thing I notice is that the transaction is in the “US” branch, but the details are in the “EU” branch. Is there a way, via the REST API, to query journal transactions/details, and discern what currency the debit/credit amount is represented in?

Answer (score 0):

Journal header contains CurrencyID field which should tell you what currency it belongs to.